# Repeatable shape in Canvas in WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, canvas

I want to draw a shape, that will be a rectangle with many circle holes. It should looks a little bit like *Connect four* game board. I was wondering whether is it possible to draw it without any code-behind helpers or loops.

So far I have done single element:

```
    <Canvas>
        <Path Fill="Red">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Xor">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 60, 60" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25" Center="30,30" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```

Is it possible to multiple this element only in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VisualBrush` as background for the `Canvas` and specify your geometry as visual of the brush. Here is an example:

```
    <Canvas Width="200" Height="200">
      <Canvas.Background>
        <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" Viewport="0,0,0.35,0.35">
          <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Path Fill="Red">
              <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Xor">
                  <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 60, 60" />
                  </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                  <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25" Center="30,30" />
                  </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
              </Path.Data>
            </Path>
          </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
      </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
```